# Remove top horizontal line in a horizontal bar chart (Chart.js 2)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I created a horizontal grouped bar chart in Chart.js but am getting stuck on a weird problem.
The problem is that while I disabled all grid lines and borders the chart is still showing a top horizontal line which I would like to get rid off.
It is visible in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUtzv.jpg.
I also made a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bsocw1v9/

```
function create_horizontal_bar_chart(){
/**
 * Draw the chart on the correct canvas. Add the correct data sets
 * and set the correct draw type.
 */
let ctx = document.getElementById('monthly_subscription_revenue_chart').getContext("2d");
let data = {
labels: ['Diensten'],
datasets: [
    {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        backgroundColor: "rgb(0,33,86)",
        data: [2250],
        stack: 1
    },
    {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        backgroundColor: "rgb(219,219,219)",
        data: [3000],
        stack: 2
    },
    {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        backgroundColor: "rgb(240,95,0)",
        data: [750],
        stack: 3
    },
]
};
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: data,
    showScale: false,
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false
        },
        hover: {
            mode: null
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                display: false,
                gridLines: {
                    drawBorder: false,
                },
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                barPercentage: 0.9,
                gridLines: {
                    drawBorder: false,
                },
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

}

I hope someone could help me with this problem as I simply can't figure out whats causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only disabled borders on the edge of the chart (by setting `drawBorder` to `false`), not grid lines. The line that bugs you is a grid line. To disable grid lines for an axis use:

```
gridLines: {
    display: false
}
```

Look at the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) under "Grid Line Configuration".

Comment: I feel so dumb right now... thank you so much for helping me with this problem.